# C# How to loop through an array and find array with most recent date?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting

New C# learner here. I've scanned through many questions that have already been posted here; I'm sorry if I missed a question like this that has already been asked.

#### Background

A program I use produces Excel files which have names that contain the date in which they are created. Thousands of Excel files are produced which need to be sorted. My mission here is to extract information from these file names so I am able to move the file to its appropriate location upon confirmation. I am working with a program that successfully finds all associated files with a particular string. I have stored the names of these files within an array.

*Example File Name:* IMPORTANT_NAME_LISTED (TEXT) [xx-xx-xx] [HH_MM].xlsx

#### What Is Known

The date is stored within "[ ]" in month/day/year format and it 100 % consistent (meaning that every file will produce the same format, size and location of the date).

I have been trying to develop a solution which targets "." before the file extension and extract the date, but I am struggling.

#### My Strategy

I have an initial decision, making sure the array that has all of the file names stored contains values.

```
//code that extracts file names exists above
//file names which interest me are stored within "fileNameArray"

//Determine if the array that collected file names contains values

if (fileNameArray.Length > 1)
{
    for (int k = 0; k <= fileNameArray.Length; k++)
        {
            //Extract date from "[xx-xx-xx] [HH-MM]"
            //Transform MM/DD/YY to YY/MM/DD and temporarily store
            //Compare each date value that exist within the string
            //Target the most recent file - find the array index
            //(Ex: 20180831 - today's date)
        }
}
```

My problems stem from properly parsing these individual array items while retaining the array index.

Do any of you recommend a method to use?
LINQ?
Array.FindAll functionality?

I greatly appreciate the help.

-Chris

**Edit:** *Further Information about my situation...*

I have a directory of Excel files, which can be in excess of ~1-3k files. I have a program which reads the file names of all of Excel files. A lot of the heavy filtering/sorting takes place before the code I have above which I want to implement.

I have been struggling with solving the issue with respect to handling files with the same name. For example:

I have 4 files that contain the same partial name `"DILITHIUM_CRYSTYAL_FUEL_TIME"`

My program must be able to filter/search file names through the core name `"DILITHIUM_CRYSTYAL_FUEL_TIME"`. If I have more than one file with the same name, I need to be able to parse the file names in a way which isolates the time stamp within the file name and finds the most recent file.

My files will always show the time stamp, to the left of the file extension, in a 100% consistent manner.

I need to be able to extract this time stamp, and run comparisons against the other files, and isolate the file which is most up-to-date.

Comment: File names won't have date properties.  You'll likely want your array to be `FileInfo`

Comment: do not use arrays use List<T> in my opinion

Comment: You could use a regex to extract the date from the filename.

Comment: The file names that are produced by the program being used always contain file date information, contained within the brackets in this format [MM-DD-YY].

Comment: If there's ever another piece of code in your project where the date will be useful to have, maybe make a `struct` that takes in the file name in the constructor and parses the date out.  Much easier to work with.

Comment: Can you explain your comment more clearly? What does "Target" mean? Are you trying to find the array index of the most recent date? What if more than one file has the same date?

Comment: What I meant by "target" was have the program look for the first instance of "." (the start of the file extension), then reading the date to the left. I wanted to use this method because of the file consistency. I know that the date will always sit -9 units away from ".". To answer your second question, there is a second time stamp value to the right of the date "[mm-dd-yy] [hr-mm].xlsx". If I need to, I will run another compare looking at the time of day. @NetMage

Comment: is it `[hr-mm]` or `[hr_mm]` ?

Comment: @NetMage [MM-DY-YR] [HR-MM].xlsx. Also, I have edited my main post, hopefully adding further clarification. I GREATLY appreciate the help, Mage. This is the last problem I need to solve before I'm able to implement this program, which will save my team hours. All engineers on my team currently sift through these files manually...I'm sure this solution will be well-received, and I'm shocked nobody has developed something like this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also go for regex, string parsing and linq:

Working example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/veUq2N

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private static Regex fileNameFragmentPattern = new Regex(@"\[(.*?)\]\.xlsx");
    private const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

    public static void Main()
    {
        var fileNames = new List<string>();

        // Generate random file names 
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            fileNames.Add(RandomString(random.Next(8,10)) +  "_" + RandomString(random.Next(4,5)) + "_"  + "(TEXT) [" + RandomDate().ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "].xlsx");
        }

        // sort files by parsed dates
        var dateSortedFileNames = fileNames.OrderByDescending( f => ExtractDate(f));
        foreach (var fileName in dateSortedFileNames) {
            // you can do anything with sorted files here (or anywhere else below :)
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);
        }       
    }

    public static DateTime ExtractDate(string fileName) {
        var fragment = fileNameFragmentPattern.Match(fileName).Value;
        var month = int.Parse(fragment.Substring(1,2));
        var day = int.Parse(fragment.Substring(4,2));
        var year = int.Parse(fragment.Substring(7,4));
        return new DateTime(year, month, day);      
    }

    public static string RandomString(int length)
    {
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
          .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }

    public static DateTime RandomDate(int min = -9999, int max = 9999)
    {
        return DateTime.Now.AddDays(random.Next(min,max));
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create a new Regex thousands of times?

Comment: IT Man, thank you! I will be using parts of this to help me develop a solution that will work for my program.

Comment: @ParrishHusband fixed.There where no performace requirements but anyway its better to eliminate this kind of drawbacks.

Comment: @ITMan yeah I agree.  I had added additional overhead on mine also that needed to be fixed.  It's good to have multiple sets of eyes on code.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is a good choice for this, combined with `Regex` for parsing.

```
var dateRE = new Regex(@"\[(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)\] \[(\d\d-\d\d)\](?=.xlsx)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

if (fileNameArray.Length > 0) {
    var ans = fileNameArray.Select((n, i) => {
                                var dtMatch = dateRE.Match(n);
                                return new { Filename = n, Index = i, Filedate = DateTime.ParseExact(dtMatch.Groups[1].Value+" "+dtMatch.Groups[2].Value, "MM-dd-yy HH-mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) };
                            })
                           .OrderByDescending(nid => nid.Filedate)
                           .First();
}
```

If you want to process the filenames differently, you can replace `First()` with some other LINQ operation.

Comment: NetMage, thank you for your input. I need to become more comfortable with Regex, as it's incredibly powerful..although making the statements frustrates me. Edit: I will definitely be using parts of this.

Comment: @ChrisS While the details can differ, sites like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) can help with creating REs (use PCRE mode).

Comment: I updated the pattern and code to handle the time as well.

Comment: Excellent. I verified the RE on the website you mentioned. That is extremely helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-regex solution.

```
var files = new List<string>
{
    "IMPORTANT_NAME_LISTED (TEXT) [05-26-92].xlsx",
    "IMPORTANT_NAME_LISTED (TEXT) [11-02-89].xlsx",
    "IMPORTANT_NAME_LISTED (TEXT) [02-21-96].xlsx"
};

foreach (var fileName in files)
{
    var nameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
    var dateStr = nameOnly.Substring(nameOnly.Length - 9, 8);
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, "MM-dd-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date))
        Console.WriteLine(date.ToShortDateString());
}
```

Since you mention that the 'date' part of the file name is 100% consistent, and we know that the length of your 'date' will always be 8. So using that knowledge,

```
nameOnly.Substring(nameOnly.Length - 9, 8);
```

will extract the string starting right after the first `[`, and will extract `8` characters ending before `]`.

And if you're 100% positive that the file extension will always be `.xlsx`, then you can shorten the code even more.

```
foreach (var fileName in files)
{
    var dateStr = fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 14, 8);
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, "MM-dd-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date))
        Console.WriteLine(date.ToShortDateString());    
}
```

Comment: Sach, thanks for your input. I like this example a lot. I will be developing the solution tonight/into the weekend and will be sure to report back!

Comment: You're welcome. And just to be safe, you should use `DateTime.TryParseExact()` instead of `DateTime.ParseExact()`. You can never be too careful. I've edited the example.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post here again, with what I used to solve my programming problem. It has been a busy past week or so, I apologize for the delay.

Here is a snippet from my code that solved my problem beautifully:

```
string scanToolDateFinalStgT1 = "";
DateTime scanToolDateFinalT1 = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 1, 1, 00);

for (int k = 0; k < scanToolT1Pass.Count(); k++)
{
    string scanToolPassNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(scanToolT1Pass[k].ToString());
    string scanToolDateStr = scanToolPassNameOnly.Substring(scanToolPassNameOnly.IndexOf("[") + 1, 8);
    string scanToolTimeStr = scanToolPassNameOnly.Substring(scanToolPassNameOnly.LastIndexOf("[") + 1, 5);
    DateTime currentScanToolDate = DateTime.ParseExact(scanToolDateStr + " " + scanToolTimeStr, "MM-dd-yy HH_mm", null);
    if (currentScanToolDate > scanToolDateFinalT1)
    {
        scanToolDateFinalT1 = currentScanToolDate;
        scanToolDateFinalStgT1 = scanToolT1Pass[k].ToString();
    }
}
```

**Information:**

This snippet is aimed at targeting '[xx-xx-xx] [xx-xx].', which is a partial unique identifier for a file name.

The program is passing in 'scanToolT1Pass', which is an array of file names. My task is to take this array and parse the file names, finding the most recent one.

'DateTime scanToolDateFinalT1' has a generic date of 1/01/200, 1:01:00, which is strictly used as a base comparison point. I am certain my data will never require dates which happen before the year 2000. I tried to have a reference date reading all zeros to compare to, but VisualStudio did not approve of that.

**Explanation:**

Are there more advanced and/or proper methods to parse this data? I'm sure there is. But, for a beginner programmer, this method makes a lot or sense to me and I aim to perfect it in the future. It was most important to me to have a program that functions first, than to invest a lot of study into polishing it.

I was able to implement similar for loops throughout my program, filtering through large amounts of data at a very rapid pace.

Thanks again to the community and to @Sach & @It Man, whose responses I was able to craft into my solution.

- Chris

Answer (score 0):

Simpler alternative :

```
var regex = new Regex(".*\[(.*)-(.*)] \[(.*)].*");

string latest = fileNameArray.OrderBy(s => regex.Replace(s, "$2$1$3")).Last();
```

Demo and explanation of the pattern can be seen on https://regex101.com/r/Ldh0sa

Answer (score -1):

```
public struct DatedExcelOutput
{
    public string FullName {  get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; }

    public DatedExcelOutput(string fileName)
    {
        FullName = fileName;
        Name = getName();
        CreationDate = parseDate();
    }
}
```

It could be called like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> fileNames = GetFiles();
var datedFiles = fileNames.Select(f => new DatedExcelOutput(f))
                                  .OrderBy(d => d.CreationDate);
```

You'll likely end up needing to sort these ascending/descending in a UI right?   So I don't think it makes sense to throw the date information away.

Edit:  Removed unnecessary IO calls as [NetMage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2557128/netmage) pointed out.

Comment: Why did you use a struct instead of a class?  Where is `parseDate` implemented?

Comment: @Amy, because it's small, and the expected behavior is immutability.  Certainly open to debate though.  If the use changes, it's always fair to re-evaluate if `struct` makes sense.

Comment: Since the OP states the filenames are retrieved by finding filenames matching a string, testing for file existence, etc. again is not necessary.

Comment: @Amy the (failed?) point of my example was to hopefully show from an OOP standpoint another option.  It's hard to tell from the original post whether or not these files will be automatically pipelined one time to their destination,or if it would be managed through a UI, or something else that may extend the lifetime of the loaded files in the application.  I didn't need to flesh out implementation details to express intent, but maybe it was received as incomplete.

Comment: @Amy I will concede though that after re-reading OP's post, it's clear he's looking for specifics in regards to parsing the date out, so I actually do agree in that sense I completely missed the mark in that regard.

Comment: Don't like doing operations especially that involve the filesystem for no reason. You will be running much slower than necessary, and considering thoousands of files are involved, your performance slowdown will probably be noticeable.

Comment: @NetMage yeah that's a fair point, OP did say thousands of files.

Comment: Parrish, Thank you for the input! I have a lot I need to take into consideration now. I appreciate the assistance A LOT.